# Getting rid of this margin and vertical height and alignment

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm trying to make a website for me but i'm having some problems.

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

[Photoshop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESBqJ.png)

And this is what i have so far

[Actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqUp1.jpg)

Here are the problems i'm currently facing:

1. I can't get rid of the white space below the navigation bar, i removed the margin and padding of both the navigation and the rest of the window but it doesn't work.
2. I can't properly align the text vertically in the middle like in the first image. I tried using line height and padding but when i resize the browser window vertically the text doesn't respond to the size.
   I want it to stay in the middle no matter what size the browser window is.
3. What's the best way of getting the background image to fit the size of the window? currently i'm using

   width:100%;
   height:100vh;
   background-image:url("Images/background.jpg");
   background-size:100% 100%;

But i feel like it's not the best way to do this

Here is my document so far:

```css
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #272727;
  border-top: 2px solid #5e20d1;
  text-align: center;
}
#navigation a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #747272;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
}
#navigation a:hover {
  color: white;
}
#jumbo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/D1cF3ZG.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#jumbo li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 1%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#jumbo h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="jumbo">
  <h1>Responsive Front-end Developer</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>HTML</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
    <li>JQUERY</li>
    <li>WORDPRESS</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me fix all these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have to add `padding-top: 1px;` to `#jumbo` or remove the margin-top from your h1.

2) Use a wrapper to align you text. Then apply `top:50%; transform:translate(0, -50%);`to it

3) #jumbo { background-size: cover; }

```css
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #272727;
  border-top: 2px solid #5e20d1;
  text-align: center;
}
#navigation a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #747272;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
}
#navigation a:hover {
  color: white;
}
#jumbo {
 text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/D1cF3ZG.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
#jumbo li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 1%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#jumbo h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  /*background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);*/
}
.teaser {
 position:relative;
 /*background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);*/
 top:50%;
 transform:translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="jumbo">
<div class="teaser">
<h1>Responsive Front-end Developer</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>HTML</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
    <li>JQUERY</li>
    <li>WORDPRESS</li>
  </ul>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixes almost all of my issues except i have to set the height of #jumbo to like 93vh to fit the screen and i get a little scroll bar when i resize the page vertically
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed it!
I made the navigation bar a position of fixed, a higher z index than the jumbo and a width of 100%
That fixed all my issues, thank you very much!

Comment: In addition here is a very good article about centering text vertically: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/  maybe you also want to have a look at this resource: http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

To remove the unwanted margins and paddings you can simply add the following at the top of your CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This will remove the margin from **ALL** elements, unless otherwise declared beneath the `*` selector.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6h0L41h/1/) example for the `*` selector

---

Alternatively you can add `margin-top:0;` to the `#jumbo h1` to remove only the whitespace between your header and content.

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/naxwev8j/1/) for the `margin-top`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1) That whitespace is just `margin-top` of h1.

2) Use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

3) [Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I'm gonna read about flexbox but 3rd is not quite what i want, i want to be able to scroll down and have each of these "boxes" be the size of the screen

https://i.gyazo.com/85384369cd51d55ab883de1cbd594a3c.png

Comment: There's only one "box" in your example, but ok. In your case I would go with flexbox - flex wrapper with navigation (fixed height) and content (it will fill the rest of screen) and every item in content is one "box" with `width: 100%; height: 100%` to fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add this to get rid of the white space (it's coming from the h1 tag).**

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

You can see this by right clicking on the h1 tag and clicking inspect.

**2. Centering text inside a div**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) for details.

**3. Perfect full page background images**

CSS Tricks has [a great post](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your problems as you mentioned
1- H1 tag by default has margin top and down so the margin-top of H1 tag causes the issue to get rid of it you have to remove it

```
#jumbo h1 {
   color: white;
   font-size: 30px;
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 20px;

}
```

2- you have to wrap the content of the jumbtron inside new container and then give the jumbtron display table and the wrapper display table-cell and vertical align middle;

```
 <div id="jumbo">
 <div class="wrapper">
 <h1>Responsive Front-end Developer</h1>
 <ul>
 <li>HTML</li>
 <li>CSS</li>
 <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
 <li>JQUERY</li>
 <li>WORDPRESS</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#jumbo {
 display:table;
 }
#jumbo .wrapper{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

here is a complete article on how to [align vertically](http://w34.co/tutorials/5-ways-to-align-elements-vertically/)
3- the best way is

```
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
```

100vh is not common in all browsers

Comment: What's a alternative to 100vh?
height:100%; doesn't make the background fit the entire screen
Everything else is as it should be now :) Thank you :)

Comment: to use 100%; the parents should have 100% as well ,I mean you have to state html,body{height:100%} but you will have an issue which is the top navigation has a part of this height so you can fix it by #jubmo{height:calc(100% - 50px)} where 50px is the height of the top nav

Answer (score 0):

1. Your body may be having some padding/margin. So make it zero like`body{margin:0; padding:0}` and apply `#jumbo h1{margin: 0;}`

2.apply `#jumbo{text-align:center;position: relative;}`. then add an extra div like this `<div class='v-block'><h1>Responsive Front-end Developer</h1><ul><li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JAVASCRIPT</li><li>JQUERY</li><li>WORDPRESS</li></ul></div>` and add the css like  `.v-block{height: 80px;position: absolute;width: 100%;top: 50%;margin-top: -40px;}`

3. background-size: cover; this will avoid stretching of the background image.

the final code is below..

```css
body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #navigation ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #272727;
                border-top: 2px solid #5e20d1;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #navigation a {
                display: inline-block;
                color: #747272;
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 15px;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                margin: 0;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            #navigation li {
                display: inline;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #navigation a:hover {
                color: white;
            }
            #jumbo {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 90vh;
                background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/D1cF3ZG.jpg");
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                background-size: cover;
            }
            #jumbo li {
                display: inline;
                margin: 1%;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            #jumbo h1 {
                color: white;
                font-size: 30px;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .v-block{
                height: 80px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -40px;
            }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="jumbo">
            <div class='v-block'>
                <h1>Responsive Front-end Developer</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>HTML</li>
                    <li>CSS</li>
                    <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
                    <li>JQUERY</li>
                    <li>WORDPRESS</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: if you want ".v-block" with dynamic height, you can use simple javascript/jquery to apply the margin-top value. the margin-top should be the half of the height of that div.